# grapeでのContent-Typeでの処理の切り分け方を教えてください

Tags: ruby, grape, rack

## 質問

grapeを使ってAPIを作成しています.
(ruby on railsやsinatoraなどの他のフレームワークは使っていません.grape単体です.)

requestのhttp headerのcontent-typeをチェックし,値が「application/x-www-form-urlencoded」かどうかで
処理を切り分けたいのですが,やり方がわかりません.

## 試したこと

headers['Content-Type']では値を取得できませんでした.

## 補足

rackの仕組みを使っての解決策(「config.ruにこう書けばできる」)でも結構です.

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました.

```
class MyRackMiddleware

  def initialize(app)
    @app=app
 end

  def call(env)
     unless env["CONTENT_TYPE"]=='application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
       raise
     end
    @app.call(env)
  end

end
```

↑こんな感じでmiddlewareを作成してconfig.ruの中で呼び出せば行けました.

```
use MyRackMiddleware
run  API
```